# How to perform Loop subdivision on a triangle mesh with Mathematica?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, smoothing

(Cross posted on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1338790?p_p_auth=3vORFCPD))

Every now and then, the question pops up how a given geometric mesh (e.g. a `MeshRegion`) can be refined to produce a (i) finer and (ii) smoother mesh. For example, the following triangle mesh from the example database is pretty coarse.

```
R = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "MeshRegion"]
MeshCellCount[R, 2]
```

[image]

> 5660

Well, we *could* execute this

```
S = DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.01}]
MeshCellCount[S, 2]
```

[image]

> 1332378

only to learn that the visual appearance hasn't improved at all.

So, how can we refine it a smoothing way with Mathematica? There are several subdivision schemes known in geometry processing, e.g. [Loop subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_subdivision_surface) for triangle meshes and [Catmull-Clark subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) for general polyhedral meshes, but there seem to be no built-in methods for these.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

We need quite a bit of preparation. In the first place we need methods to compute cell adjacency matrices from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160443/how-to-obtain-the-cell-adjacency-graph-of-a-mesh/160457#160457). I copied the code for completeness.

```
CellAdjacencyMatrix[R_MeshRegion, d_, 0] := If[MeshCellCount[R, d] > 0,
   Unitize[R["ConnectivityMatrix"[d, 0]]],
   {}
   ];

CellAdjacencyMatrix[R_MeshRegion, 0, d_] := If[MeshCellCount[R, d] > 0,
   Unitize[R["ConnectivityMatrix"[0, d]]],
   {}
   ];

CellAdjacencyMatrix[R_MeshRegion, 0, 0] := 
  If[MeshCellCount[R, 1] > 0,
   With[{A = CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 0, 1]},
    With[{B = A.Transpose[A]},
     SparseArray[B - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[B]]]
     ]
    ],
   {}
   ];

CellAdjacencyMatrix[R_MeshRegion, d1_, d2_] := 
  If[(MeshCellCount[R, d1] > 0) && (MeshCellCount[R, d2] > 0), 
   With[{B = CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, d1, 0].CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 0, d2]},
    SparseArray[
     If[d1 == d2,
      UnitStep[B - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[B]] - d1],
      UnitStep[B - (Min[d1, d2] + 1)]
      ]
     ]
    ],
   {}
   ];
```

Alternatively to copying the code above, simply make sure that you have [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html) version 0.3.93 or later installed and run

```
Needs["IGraphM`"];
CellAdjacencyMatrix = IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix;
```

Next is a `CompiledFunction` to compute the triangle faces for the new mesh:

```
getSubdividedTriangles = 
  Compile[{{ff, _Integer, 1}, {ee, _Integer, 1}},
   {
    {Compile`GetElement[ff, 1],Compile`GetElement[ee, 3],Compile`GetElement[ee, 2]},
    {Compile`GetElement[ff, 2],Compile`GetElement[ee, 1],Compile`GetElement[ee, 3]},
    {Compile`GetElement[ff, 3],Compile`GetElement[ee, 2],Compile`GetElement[ee, 1]},
    ee
    },
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Finally, the method that webs everything together. It assembles the subdivision matrix (which maps the old vertex coordinates to the new ones), uses it to compute the new positions and calls `getSubdividedTriangles` in order to generate the new triangle faces.

```
ClearAll[LoopSubdivide];
Options[LoopSubdivide] = {
   "VertexWeightFunction" -> 
    Function[n, 5./8. - (3./8. + 1./4. Cos[(2. Pi)/n])^2],
   "EdgeWeight" -> 3./8.,
   "AverageBoundary" -> True
   };

LoopSubdivide[R_MeshRegion, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  LoopSubdivide[{R, {{0}}}, opts][[1]];

LoopSubdivide[{R_MeshRegion, A_?MatrixQ}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{A00, A10, A12, A20, B00, B10, n, n0, n1, n2, βn, pts, 
   newpts, edges, faces, edgelookuptable, triangleneighedges, 
   newfaces, subdivisionmatrix, bndedgelist, bndedges, bndvertices, 
   bndedgeQ, intedgeQ, bndvertexQ, 
   intvertexQ, β, βbnd, η},
  pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
  A10 = CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 1, 0];
  A20 = CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 2, 0];
  A12 = CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 1, 2];
  edges = MeshCells[R, 1, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
  faces = MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
  n0 = Length[pts];
  n1 = Length[edges];
  n2 = Length[faces];
  edgelookuptable = SparseArray[
    Rule[
     Join[edges, Transpose[Transpose[edges][[{2, 1}]]]], 
     Join[Range[1, Length[edges]], Range[1, Length[edges]]]
     ],
    {n0, n0}];
  (*A00=CellAdjacencyMatrix[R,0,0];*)
  A00 = Unitize[edgelookuptable];
  bndedgelist = Flatten[Position[Total[A12, {2}], 1]];
  If[Length[bndedgelist] > 0, bndedges = edges[[bndedgelist]];
   bndvertices = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[bndedges]]];
   bndedgeQ = SparseArray[Partition[bndedgelist, 1] -> 1, {n1}];
   bndvertexQ = SparseArray[Partition[bndvertices, 1] -> 1, {n0}];
   B00 = SparseArray[Join[bndedges, Reverse /@ bndedges] -> 1, {n0, n0}];
   B10 = SparseArray[Transpose[{Join[bndedgelist, bndedgelist], Join @@ Transpose[bndedges]}] -> 1, {n1, n0}];, 
   bndedgeQ = SparseArray[{}, {Length[edges]}];
   bndvertexQ = SparseArray[{}, {n0}];
   B00 = SparseArray[{}, {n0, n0}];
   B10 = SparseArray[{}, {n1, n0}];
  ];
  intedgeQ = SparseArray[Subtract[1, Normal[bndedgeQ]]];
  intvertexQ = SparseArray[Subtract[1, Normal[bndvertexQ]]];
  n = Total[A10];
  β = OptionValue["VertexWeightFunction"];
  η = OptionValue["EdgeWeight"];
  βn = β /@ n;
  βbnd = If[TrueQ[OptionValue["AverageBoundary"]], 1./8., 0.];
  subdivisionmatrix = Join[
    Plus[
     DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[1. - βn] intvertexQ + (1. - 2. βbnd) bndvertexQ],
     SparseArray[(βn/n intvertexQ)] A00, 
     βbnd B00
     ], 
    Plus @@ {
      ((3. η - 1.) intedgeQ) (A10), 
      If[Abs[η - 0.5] < Sqrt[$MachineEpsilon], Nothing, ((0.5 - η) intedgeQ) (A12.A20)], 0.5 B10}
    ];
  newpts = subdivisionmatrix.pts;
  triangleneighedges = Module[{f1, f2, f3},
    {f1, f2, f3} = Transpose[faces];
    Partition[
     Extract[
      edgelookuptable,
      Transpose[{Flatten[Transpose[{f2, f3, f1}]], Flatten[Transpose[{f3, f1, f2}]]}]],
     3]
    ];
  newfaces = 
   Flatten[getSubdividedTriangles[faces, triangleneighedges + n0], 
    1];

  {
   MeshRegion[newpts, Polygon[newfaces]],
   subdivisionmatrix
   }
  ]
```

**Test examples**

So, let's test it. A classical example is subdividing an `"Isosahedron"`:

```
R = RegionBoundary@PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "MeshRegion"];
regions = NestList[LoopSubdivide, R, 5]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 
g = GraphicsGrid[Partition[regions, 3], ImageSize -> Full]
```

> 0.069731

[image]

Now, let's tackle the `"Triceratops"` from above:

```
R = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "MeshRegion"];
regions = NestList[LoopSubdivide, R, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
g = GraphicsGrid[Partition[regions, 3], ImageSize -> Full]
```

> 0.270776

[image]

The meshes so far had trivial boundary. As for an example with nontrivial boundary, I dug out the `"Vase"` from the example dataset:

```
R = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Vase"}, "MeshRegion"];
regions = NestList[LoopSubdivide, R, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 
g = GraphicsRow[
  Table[Show[S, ViewPoint -> {1.4, -2.1, -2.2}, 
    ViewVertical -> {1.7, -0.6, 0.0}], {S, regions}], 
  ImageSize -> Full]
```

> 1.35325

[image]

**Edit**

Added some performance improvements and incorporated some ideas by [Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346) form [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160443/how-to-obtain-the-cell-adjacency-graph-of-a-mesh/166491#166491).

Added options for customization of the subdivision process, in particular for planar subdivision (see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170604/38178) for an application example).

Added a way to return also the subdivision matrix since it can be useful, e.g. for [geometric multigrid solvers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173617/38178). Just call with a matrix as second argument, e.g., `LoopSubdivide[R,{{1}}]`.

Fixed a bug that produced dense subdivision matrices in some two-dimensional examples due to not using `0` as `"Background"` value.

Comment: `MeshRegion @@ PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Faces"]` returns an error, probably you meant `PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "MeshRegion"]`. But with this the result is far from what you showed (version 11.2.0).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Hm. On 11.0.1, it works with `"Faces"` (which I found surprising by myself).  `PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "MeshRegion"]` is pretty broken for me, too. There are probably some nonmanifold edges hanging around. Does the fix `R = MeshRegion @@ 
  Cases[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", 
     "Graphics3D"] , _GraphicsComplex][[1]]` work for you>

Comment: Yes, it does work. Is it expected that `Volume` returns `0` in the all cases?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, they are surfaces. Ah, I see, `PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "MeshRegion"]` is volumetric...

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, I really appreciate that!

Comment: Well, your routines were fun to play with, and some meshes I held off experimenting due to their roughness were dealt with by your routines. :) There are a few parts that could be slightly tweaked, but that's for another time...

Comment: @J.M. Suggestions are always welcome, in particular since I use a similar routine for everyday work! I know already, that some matrix-matrix multiplications may be replaced by suitable matrix-vector multiplications (e.g. `(A12.A20).pts` could read `A12.(A20.pts)` and even `A12` might be decomposed into `A10` and `A21` plus some minor tweaking) but the subdivision matrices may be interesting on their own, e.g. for constructing multigrid methods for solving linear equations. However, I have not found the time, yet, to experiment with that. =/

Comment: @J.M. Btw.: Is that a DNA granny knot in your new avatar? ^^

Comment: Yes, very perceptive of you. ;) I acknowledged your help with making "Granny's DNA" (title subject to change) in my profile page.

Comment: `MeshCells` no longer takes the argument  `"Multicells"` (it turns up in red in mathematica). Could you please correct this in your code?

Comment: As long as I have used it `"Multicell"` has always been rendered in red, because the code highlighter did not know about it. It should work anyways...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: You're welcome.