# A geometric multigrid solver for Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, mesh, finite-element-method, sparse-arrays

*Cross posted to [community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1351062)*

Mathematica ships a variety of linear solvers through the interface

```
LinearSolve[A, b, Method -> method]
```

the most notable for sparse matrix `A` being:

- `"Multifrontal"` - the default solver for sparse arrays; direct solver based on a spare LU-factorization performed with UMFPACK. Big advantage: `LinearSolve[A]` creates a `LinearSolveFunction` object that can be reused.
- `"Cholesky"` - a direct solver using the sparse Cholesky-factorization provided by TAUCS. Also produces a `LinearSolveFunction` but limited to positive-definite matrices.
- `"Pardiso"` - a parallelized direct solver from the Intel MKL; undocumented but much faster and not nearly as memory hungry as `"Multifrontal"`. `LinearSolve[A, Method -> "Pardiso"]` creates a reusable `LinearSolveFunction` object as well. The original Intel MKL Pardiso solver can do quite a lot more! Unfortunately, many of its features such as reusing symbolic factorizations are not accessible via `LinearSolve`. (Or are they? That would be great to know!)
- `"Krylov"` with the submethods `"ConjugateGradient"`, `"GMRES"`, and `"BiCGSTAB"` - iterative solvers that require good preconditioners and good starting values. These are supposed to work quite well for transient PDEs with smoothly varying coefficients.

See [this site](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixComputations.html#81663253) for reference. (It is a bit outdated but I don't think that any essential changes were made in the meantime - apart from `"Pardiso"`.).

I mostly use linear solvers to solve PDEs, mostly elliptic ones, but also parabolic ones every now and then. On the one hand, the direct solvers hit the wall when dealing with meshes with several million degrees of freedom. And in particular, if the meshes are 3-dimensional, factorization times explode due to the high fill-in. On the other hand, the iterative solvers within Mathematica -- if I am honest -- perform so poorly on elliptic problems that I used to question the mental sanity of several numericists who told me that I had to use an iterative solver for *every* linear system of size larger than $5 \times 5$.

Some time ago, I learnt that the big thing would be multigrid solvers. So I wonder whether one can implement such a solver in Mathematica (be it in the native language or via LibraryLink) and how it would compare to the built-in linear solvers.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## Background

Details about multigrid solvers can be found in this [pretty neat script](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/LEHRE/MULTIGRID/multigrid.pdf) by Volker John. That's basically the source from which I drew the information to implement the V-cycle solver below.

In a nutshell, a multigrid solver builds on two ingredients: A hierarchy of linear systems (with so-called *prolongation operators* mapping between them) and a family of *smoothers*.

## Implementation

### CG-method as smoother

I use an iterative conjugate-gradient solver as smoother. For some reason, Mathematica's conjugate-gradient solver has an exorbitantly high latency, so I use my own implementation which I wrote several years ago. It's really easy to implement; all necessary details can be found, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_resulting_algorithm). Note that my implementation returns an `Association` that also provides some information on the solving process. (In particular for transient PDE with varying coefficients, the number of iterations required to reduce the residuum below a given tolerance is often a valuable information that one might want to use, e.g., for determining whether the preconditioner has to be updated.)

```
ClearAll[CGLinearSolve];

Options[CGLinearSolve] = {
   "Tolerance" -> 10^(-8),
   "StartingVector" -> Automatic,
   MaxIterations -> 1000,
   "Preconditioner" -> Identity
   };

CGLinearSolve[A_?SquareMatrixQ, b_?MatrixQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   CGLinearSolve[A, #, opts] & /@ Transpose[b]

CGLinearSolve[A_?SquareMatrixQ, b_?VectorQ, OptionsPattern[]] :=

  Module[{r, u, δ, δ0, p, ρ, ρold, 
    z, α, β, x, TOL, iter, P, precdata, normb, maxiter},
   P = OptionValue["Preconditioner"];
   maxiter = OptionValue[MaxIterations];
   normb = Sqrt[b.b];
   If[Head[P] === String,
    precdata = SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[A, "Method" -> P];
    P = x \[Function] SparseArray`SparseMatrixApplyILU[precdata, x];
    ];
   If[P === Automatic,
    precdata = SparseArray`SparseMatrixILU[A, "Method" -> "ILU0"];
    P = x \[Function] SparseArray`SparseMatrixApplyILU[precdata, x];
    ];
   TOL = normb OptionValue["Tolerance"];
   If[OptionValue["StartingVector"] === Automatic,
    x = ConstantArray[0., Dimensions[A][[2]]];
    r = b
    ,
    x = OptionValue["StartingVector"];
    r = b - A.x;
    ];
   z = P[r];
   p = z;
   ρ = r.z;
   δ0 = δ = Sqrt[r.r];
   iter = 0;
   While[δ > TOL && iter < maxiter,
    iter++;
    u = A.p;
    α = ρ/(p.u);
    x = x + α p;
    ρold = ρ;
    r = r - α u;
    δ = Sqrt[r.r];
    z = P[r];
    ρ = r.z;
    β = ρ/ρold;
    p = z + β p;
    ];
   Association[
    "Solution" -> x,
    "Iterations" -> iter,
    "Residual" -> δ,
    "RelativeResidual" -> Quiet[Check[δ/δ0, ∞]],
    "NormalizedResidual" -> Quiet[Check[δ/normb, ∞]]
    ]
   ];
```

### Weighted Jacobi smoother

The [weighted Jacobi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Convergence_in_the_symmetric_positive_definite_case) is a very simply iterative solver that employs Richardson iterations with the diagonal of the matrix as preconditioner (the matrix must not have any zero elements on the diagonal!) and a bit of damping. Works in general only for diagonally dominant matrices and positive-definite matrices (if the `"Weight"` is chosen sufficiently small). It's not really bad but it is not excellent either. In the test problem below, it usually necessitates one more V-cycle as the CG smoother.

```
Options[JacobiLinearSolve] = {
   "Tolerance" -> 10^(-8),
   "StartingVector" -> Automatic,
   MaxIterations -> 1000,
   "Weight" -> 2./3.
   };

JacobiLinearSolve[A_?SquareMatrixQ, b_?MatrixQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  JacobiLinearSolve[A, #, opts] & /@ Transpose[b]

JacobiLinearSolve[A_?SquareMatrixQ, b_?VectorQ, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{ω, x, r, ωd, dd, iter, δ, δ0, normb, TOL, maxiter},
   ω = OptionValue["Weight"];
   maxiter = OptionValue[MaxIterations];
   normb = Max[Abs[b]];
   TOL = normb OptionValue["Tolerance"];
   If[OptionValue["StartingVector"] === Automatic,
    x = ConstantArray[0., Dimensions[A][[2]]];
    r = b;
    ,
    x = OptionValue["StartingVector"];
    r = b - A.x;
    ];
   ωd = ω/Normal[Diagonal[A]];
   δ = δ0 = Max[Abs[r]];
   iter = 0;
   While[δ > TOL && iter < maxiter,
    iter++;
    x += ωd r;
    r = (b - A.x);
    δ = Max[Abs[r]];
    ];
   Association[
    "Solution" -> x,
    "Iterations" -> iter,
    "Residual" -> δ,
    "RelativeResidual" -> Quiet[Check[δ/δ0, ∞]],
    "NormalizedResidual" -> Quiet[Check[δ/normb, ∞]]
    ]
   ];
```

### Setting up the solver

Next is a function that takes the system matrix `Matrix` and a family of prologation operators `Prolongations` and creates a `GMGLinearSolveFunction` object. This object contains a linear solving method for the deepest level in the hierarchy, the prolongation operators, and - derived from `Matrix` and `Prolongations` - a linear system matrix for each level in the hierarchy.

As it is the core idea of Galerkin schemes in FEM, we interpret the system matrix `Matrix` on the finest grid as a linear operator $A_0 \colon X_0 \to X_0'$, where $X_0$ denotes the finite element function space of continuous, piecewise-linear functions on the finest mesh and $X_0'$ denotes its dual space. Denoting the finite element function space on the $i$-th subgrid by $X_i$ and interpreting the prolongation operators in the list `Prolongations` as linear embeddings $J_i \colon X_{i} \hookrightarrow X_{i-1}$, we obtain the linear operators $A_i \colon X_i \to X_i'$ by *Galerkin subspace <s>projection</s> pullback*, i.e. by requiring that the following diagram is commutative:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_0 @<{J_1}<< X_1 @<{J_2}<< \dotsm @<{J_{n-1}}<< X_{n-1} @<{J_{n}}<< X_n\\
@VV{A_0}V @VV{A_1}V @. @VV{A_{n-1}}V @VV{A_{n}}V\\
X_0' @>{J_1'}>> X_1' @>{J_2'}>> \dotsm @>{J_{n-1}'}>> X_{n-1}' @>{J_{n}'}>> X_n'
\end{CD}$$

Per default, `LinearSolve` is used as solver for the coarsest grid, but the user may specify any other function `F` via the option "CoarsestGridSolver" -> F.

Some pretty-printing for the created `GMGLinearSolveFunction` objects is also added.

```
ClearAll[GMGLinearSolve, GMGLinearSolveFunction];

GMGLinearSolve[
   Matrix_?SquareMatrixQ,
   Prolongations_List,
   OptionsPattern[{
     "CoarsestGridSolver" -> LinearSolve
     }]
   ] := Module[{A},
   (*Galerkin subspace projections of the system matrix*)
   A = FoldList[Transpose[#2].(#1.#2) &, Matrix, Prolongations];
   GMGLinearSolveFunction[
    Association[
     "MatrixHierarchy" -> A,
     "Prolongations" -> Prolongations,
     "CoarsestGridSolver" -> OptionValue["CoarsestGridSolver"][A[[-1]]],
     "CoarsestGridSolverFunction" -> OptionValue["CoarsestGridSolver"]
     ]
    ]
   ];

GMGLinearSolveFunction /: 
  MakeBoxes[S_GMGLinearSolveFunction, StandardForm] := 
  BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[GMGLinearSolveFunction, "", 
   BoxForm`GenericIcon[LinearSolveFunction],
   {
    {
     BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Specified elements: ", 
       Length[S[[1, "MatrixHierarchy", 1]]["NonzeroValues"]]}, 
      StandardForm]
     },
    {
     BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Dimensions: ", 
       Dimensions[S[[1, "MatrixHierarchy", 1]]]}, StandardForm],
     BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Depth: ", 
       Length[S[[1, "MatrixHierarchy"]]]}, StandardForm]
     }
    },
   {
    BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{
      Invisible["Dimensions: "],
      Column[Dimensions /@ S[[1, "MatrixHierarchy", 2 ;;]]]},
     StandardForm],
    BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{
      "CoarsestGridSolver: ",
      S[[1, "CoarsestGridSolverFunction"]]
      }, StandardForm]
    },
   StandardForm, "Interpretable" -> False
   ];
```

### The solver

The following is the actual V-cycle solver. To my own surpise, the algorithm was not that hard to implement. As always, most work had to be invested into the user interface (and it's still not complete as it lacks bulletproofing against 1D-10T errors).

Actually, this V-cycle solver is a purely algebraic solver (AMG); the *geometry* in "geometric multigrid solver" lies within the way the matrix hierarchy was constructed (namely by geometrically nested grids and Galerkin subspace methods).

```
Options[GMGLinearSolveFunction] = {
   "StartingVector" -> Automatic,
   "Tolerance" -> 1. 10^-8,
   "MaxIterations" -> 25,
   "StartingVectorSmoothingCounts" -> 12,
   "PreSmoothingCounts" -> 8,
   "PostSmoothingCounts" -> 8,
   "Smoother" -> Function[
     {A, b, x0, ν, p},
     (
      CGLinearSolve[A, b,
        MaxIterations -> ν,
        "StartingVector" -> x0,
        "Tolerance" -> 10^-12
        ]["Solution"]
      )
     ],
   "SmootherParameters" -> None
   };

GMGLinearSolveFunction /: GMGLinearSolveFunction[a_Association][
   Rhs_?VectorQ,
   opts0 : OptionsPattern[]
   ] := With[{
    J = a["Prolongations"],
    A = a["MatrixHierarchy"],
    Asol = a["CoarsestGridSolver"]
    },
   Module[{smoother, Rhsnorm, p, n, v, f, depth, allocationtime, startingvector, startingvectortime, solvetime, startingvectorresidual, residual, ν0, ν1, ν2, tol, maxiter, iter, opts},
    opts = Merge[{
       Options[GMGLinearSolveFunction],
       opts0
       }, Last
      ];
    n = Length /@ A;
    depth = Length[n];

    smoother = opts["Smoother"];
    p = opts["SmootherParameters"];
    If[p === None, p = ConstantArray[{}, depth];];

    (* allocate memory for computations *)

    allocationtime = AbsoluteTiming[
       v = ConstantArray[0., #] & /@ n;
       f = Join[{Rhs}, ConstantArray[0., #] & /@ Most[n]];
       ][[1]];

    (* compute starting vector *)

    startingvectortime = AbsoluteTiming[
       If[VectorQ[opts["StartingVector"]],
        v[[1]] = opts["StartingVector"];
        ,
        If[opts["StartingVector"] =!= "Null", opts["StartingVector"] == Automatic];];

       If[opts["StartingVector"] === Automatic,
        Module[{b},
          ν0 = opts["StartingVectorSmoothingCounts"];
          If[! ListQ[ν0], ν0 = If[IntegerQ[ν0], ConstantArray[ν0, Length[n] - 1], ν0 /@ Range[depth]]];
          b = FoldList[#1.#2 &, Rhs, J];
          v[[depth]] = Asol[b[[depth]]];

          Do[v[[i]] = smoother[A[[i]], b[[i]], J[[i]].v[[i + 1]], ν0[[i]], p[[i]]], {i, depth - 1, 1, -1}];
          ];
        ,
        ν0 = None;
        ];
       ][[1]];
    startingvector = v[[1]];
    residual = startingvectorresidual = Max[Abs[Rhs - A[[1]].startingvector]];

    (* perform V-cycles until tolerance is met *)

    solvetime = AbsoluteTiming[
       ν1 = opts["PreSmoothingCounts"];
       If[! ListQ[ν1], ν1 = If[IntegerQ[ν1], ConstantArray[ν1, Length[n] - 1], ν1 /@ Range[depth]]];
       ν2 = opts["PostSmoothingCounts"];
       If[! ListQ[ν2], ν2 = If[IntegerQ[ν2], ConstantArray[ν2, Length[n] - 1], ν2 /@ Range[depth]]];
       Rhsnorm = Max[Abs[Rhs]];
       tol = opts["Tolerance"] Rhsnorm;
       maxiter = opts["MaxIterations"];
       iter = 0;
       While[
        residual > tol && iter < maxiter,
        iter++;
        Do[
         v[[i]] = smoother[A[[i]], f[[i]], N[Boole[i == 1]] v[[i]], ν1[[i]], p[[i]]];
         f[[i + 1]] = (f[[i]] - A[[i]].v[[i]]).J[[i]],
         {i, 1, depth - 1}];

        (* solve at deepest level with "CoarsestGridSolver" *)

         v[[depth]] = Asol[f[[depth]]];

        Do[
         v[[i]] = smoother[A[[i]], f[[i]], v[[i]] + J[[i]].v[[i + 1]], ν2[[i]], p[[i]]],
         {i, depth - 1, 1, -1}];
        residual = Max[Abs[Subtract[Rhs, A[[1]].v[[1]]]]];
        ];
       ][[1]];

    Association[
     "Solution" -> v[[1]],
     "StartingVectorResidual" -> startingvectorresidual,
     "StartingVectorNormalizedResidual" -> 
      startingvectorresidual/Rhsnorm,
     "Residual" -> residual,
     "NormalizedResidual" -> residual/Rhsnorm,
     "SuccessQ" -> residual < tol,
     "Timings" -> Dataset@Association[
        "Total" -> allocationtime + startingvectortime + solvetime,
        "Allocation" -> allocationtime,
        "StartingVector" -> startingvectortime,
        "V-Cycle" -> solvetime
        ],
     "V-CycleCount" -> iter,
     "SmootingCounts" -> Dataset@Association[
        "StartingVector" -> {ν0},
        "Pre" -> {ν1},
        "Post" -> {ν2}
        ],
     "StartingVector" -> startingvector,
     "Smoother" -> smoother,
     "Depth" -> depth
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

## Application

What we need now is a test case! *Just by chance*, I have recently updated my [Loop subdivision routine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161332/38178) such that it also returns the subdivision matrix if we ask kindly. We can use these subdivision matrices as prolongation operators!

So, let's start with a rather coarse mesh on the unit disk and refine it by Loop subdivision (you will need the code for [LoopSubdivide](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161332/38178) if you want to try this):

```
R = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
depth = 5;
{R, J} = {Last[#1], Reverse[Rest[#2]]} & @@ 
   Transpose@NestList[LoopSubdivide, {R, {{0}}}, depth - 1];
```

Let's solve the following elliptic problem with Neumann boundary conditions on the disk $\varOmega$:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
 (\varepsilon - \Delta) \, u &= &f, & \text{in $\varOmega\setminus \partial \varOmega$,}\\
 \nu \,u&= &0, & \text{on $\partial \varOmega$.}
\end{array}$$

We can use Mathematica's FEM capacities to assemble the system matrix and the right hand side for us:

```
f = X \[Function] 
   16. Sinc[4. Pi Sqrt[Abs[Dot[X + 0.5, X + 0.5]]]] - 
    16. Sinc[4. Pi Sqrt[Abs[Dot[X - 0.5, X - 0.5]]]] + 
    N[Sign[X[[2]]]] + N[Sign[X[[1]]]];
fvec = Map[f, MeshCoordinates[R]];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Rdiscr = ToElementMesh[
   R,
   "MeshOrder" -> 1,
   "NodeReordering" -> False,
   MeshQualityGoal -> 0
   ];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {Rdiscr}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[2]}}, 
   "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}, "LoadCoefficients" -> {{f[{x, y}]}}];
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, 
   sd, {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., True]}];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];

{b, L, damping, M} = dpde["All"];
b = Flatten[Normal[b]];
A = L + 0.0001 M;
```

Now we create a `GMGLinearSolveFunction` object and solve the equation:

```
S = GMGLinearSolve[A, J]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xGMG = S[b,
      "Tolerance" -> 1. 10^-8,
      "StartingVectorSmoothingCounts" -> 12,
      "PreSmoothingCounts" -> 8,
      "PostSmoothingCounts" -> 8
      ]["Solution"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.835408
>
> 1.04969

### Timings

Here are the timings for some other solvers:

```
xKrylov = LinearSolve[A, b, Method -> {
       "Krylov",
       "Method" -> "ConjugateGradient",
       "Preconditioner" -> "ILU0"
       }]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xTAUCS = LinearSolve[A, b, "Method" -> "Cholesky"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xUMFPACK = LinearSolve[A, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xPardiso = LinearSolve[A, b, "Method" -> "Pardiso"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 67.948
>
> 6.89134
>
> 6.0961
>
> 2.30715

Three things to observe here:

1. Mathematica's `"ConjugateGradient"` is the *absolute* loser here. (But don't ask me for `"GMRES"` or `"BiCGSTAB"`; I was not in the mood of waiting for them.)
2. `"Cholesky"` cannot convert its limitation to positive-definite matrices into any advantage. That's also why I never use it.
3. `GMGLinearSolve` is actually a bit faster than `"Pardiso"`.

### Errors

Here are the errors; I use the UMFPACK 's solution as "ground truth" (it doesn't matter, though).

```
Max[Abs[xUMFPACK - xGMG]]
Max[Abs[xUMFPACK - xTAUCS]]
Max[Abs[xUMFPACK - xPardiso]]
Max[Abs[xUMFPACK - xKrylov]]
```

> 3.90012*10^-10
>
> 1.14953*10^-9
>
> 2.45955*10^-10
>
> 6.27234*10^-10

They all have comparable accuracy. So, this simple multigrid solver, implemented within a long afternoon, seems to be at least on par with Pardiso. Not bad, is it?

### Multiple solves are still faster with direct solvers on 2D grids

Once the factorizations of the direct solvers are computed and stored in `LinearSolveFunction` objects, the actual solves (triangle forward and backward substitutions) are *much* faster. However, this is not necessarily the usage spectrum of iterative methods.
Anyways, here are some timings:

```
solUMFPACK = Quiet[LinearSolve[A]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xUMFPACK = solUMFPACK[b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
solTAUCS = LinearSolve[A, "Method" -> "Cholesky"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xTAUCS = solTAUCS[b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
solPardiso = LinearSolve[A, "Method" -> "Pardiso"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xPardiso = solPardiso[b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 6.07364
>
> 0.142823
>
> 7.28346
>
> 0.183195
>
> 2.13817
>
> 0.236214

Note that I used `Quiet` for UMFPACK because it complains about a bad condition number of the system and the error handling would add about 20(!) seconds to the timings. There is however no problem with the numerical errors:

```
Max[Abs[xGMG - xUMFPACK]]
Max[Abs[xGMG - xTAUCS]]
Max[Abs[xGMG - xPardiso]]

3.90012*10^-10

7.59533*10^-10

1.44077*10^-10
```

## Remarks

The success of multigrid solvers depends heavily on the smoothers. They have to be cheap but also efffective in getting rid of oscillations in the residuals. Using `CGLinearSolve` as smoother will probably work only for positive-(semi)definite system matrices. I might add further smoothers later.

This is a rather premature implementation and not fully tested. For example, I would also like to test it on tetrahedral meshes where multigrid methods are supposed to shine. But currently, I do not have any nice routines for creating prolongation operators.

Comment: Amazing!  By the way, do you mean "hierarchy" instead of "hierarchie"?

Comment: I did a multigrid solver in Matlab once for a HW. Used Gauss-Seidel red-black solver for smother. Mutligrid is the fastest solver there is. Was fun implementing it. Here is the full report with result comparing it to other solvers on Poisson PDE [matlab multigrid](https://www.12000.org/my_courses/UC_davis/fall_2010/math_228a/HWs/HW4/index.htm) with source code in Matlab. This was few years ago.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the link! I will have a keen look at your Gauss-Seidel smoother. My self-written SSOR was rather disappointing so I've already read about the red-black method. I will try it soon and add it here!

Comment: @QuantumDot Thank you for the hint! I corrected the typos, both in text and in code.

Comment: This is too cool. I was asking user21 about multigrid solvers in Mathematica the other month and here one appears. Very nice.

Comment: @QuantumDot its just same word another language, maybe german or dutch.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Do you happen to know which one (Pardiso or UMFPACK) is the default when one uses LinearSolve[A, b, Method->"Multifrontal"] for sparse A?

Comment: @mma `UMFPACK` is the backend for `Multifrontal`. As reference see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraMatrixComputations.html#81663253).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you, I missed that. Would be interesting to compare timings of your implementation (which is great) to UMFPACK/PARDISO with saved symbolic factorization (if possible).

Comment: Hehe. Well if the factorization time is subtracted, UMFPACK is the fastest, followed by Pardiso. Pardiso is a bit slower because it has to perform about two iterative refinements in order to account for its static pivoting (but that's also a reason why Pardiso can reuse symbolic factorization -- not the buit-in Pardiso, though).

Comment: @mmal I added some timings.

Comment: Would be a nice addition for the [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns), in case you were wondering, pull requests are welcome ;-)

Comment: In version 12 you can link your solver into `NDSolve` have a look [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/programmatic-api-to-fem.html?product=mathematica)

Comment: @user21 Thanks for the hint! That API is ab-so-lute-ly great! I'll try it after I contacted my local dealer. =D Good job!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, thanks. Let me know if there are issue.

Comment: Hey Henrik, I've been looking through John's lecture notes on multigrid, and I can't seem to find the original script your code is based on. Unfortunately, the first link in your answer apparently is a link to a Google Search, and I can't find John's stuff there. Would you happen to still have the link on you?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was not very clever of mine. I found the link and replaced it. However, I cannot promise that it will work forever...

Comment: Nice, thanks Henrik!

Answer (score 20):

## 3D Example

The problem with direct solvers is that starting in 3 dimensions, their performance for dealing with matrices stemming from PDEs drops rapidly. This is why I wanted to show at least one 3-dimensional example. As there is no immediate analogon for Loop subdivision of tetrahedral meshes, I use hexahedral meshes instead.

### Preparation

Here are some helper functions for generating the grid hierachy and the prolongation mappings. Prolongation is performed by hex-wise trilinear interpolation. This fits well since we are going to use first-order meshes.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
cubemesh[n_] := Module[{R},
  R = ArrayMesh[ConstantArray[1, ConstantArray[n, 3]], DataRange -> ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 3]];
  ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> MeshCoordinates[R],
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[ MeshCells[R, 3, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]]},
   "MeshOrder" -> 1, "NodeReordering" -> False, MeshQualityGoal -> 0
   ]
  ]

getEdges = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {idx, _Integer, 1}},
   Table[{i, Compile`GetElement[idx, j]}, {j, 1, Length[idx]}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

getProlongationOperator[Rfine_ElementMesh, Rcoarse_ElementMesh, h_] :=
   Module[{pfine, pcoarse},
   pfine = Rfine["Coordinates"];
   pcoarse = Rcoarse["Coordinates"];
   # SparseArray[1./Total[#, {2}]] &@SparseArray[
     Join @@ getEdges[
        Range[Length[pfine]],
        Nearest[pcoarse -> Automatic, pfine, {∞, h 1.1}, 
         DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance]
        ] -> 1.,
     {Length[pfine], Length[pcoarse]}, 0.
     ]
   ];
```

This creates the actual grid hierarchy and the prolongation mappings.

```
dList = Range[6, 2, -1];
nList = 2^dList;
hList = 1./(2^(dList));
RList = cubemesh /@ nList; // AbsoluteTiming // First
J = Table[ getProlongationOperator[RList[[i]], RList[[i + 1]], 
      hList[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[RList] - 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 3.84804
>
> 0.603694

Again, we solve a linear elliptic problem with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions (this is easier to implement than Dirichlet conditions). Moreover, I thought it would be a good idea to prescribe an analytic solution, so that we can discretize its right-hand side of the equation, solve the discretized PDE, and compare with the analytic solution in the end. (Notice that it is essential that `v` below satisfies the homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions.)

```
ϵ = 1.;
Quiet[
  XX = {X[[1]], X[[2]], X[[3]]};
  v = X \[Function] Cos[5 Pi X[[1]]] Cos[Pi X[[2]]] Cos[3 Pi X[[3]]];
  Δv = X \[Function] Evaluate[Tr[D[v[XX], {XX, 2}]]];
  f = X \[Function] Evaluate[ϵ v[XX] - Δv[XX]]
  ];

vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y, z}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {RList[[1]]}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[3]}},
   "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}},
   "LoadCoefficients" -> {{f[{x, y, z}]}}
   ];
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd, {DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0., True]}];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

{b, L, damping, M} = dpde["All"];
b = Flatten[Normal[b]];
A = L + ϵ M;
```

> 2.21493

The finest mesh `RList[[1]]` consists of `262144` hexahedra. The system matrix has size `{274625, 274625}` and contains `7189057` nonzero values.

### Timings

Let's get to the timings. This time, we see that the conjugate gradient solver (with "ILU0" preconditioner) performs *much* better than the direct solvers:

```
xUMFPACK = LinearSolve[A, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xPardiso = LinearSolve[A, b, Method -> "Pardiso"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
solCG = CGLinearSolve[A, b,
     "Tolerance" -> 1. 10^-6,
     "Preconditioner" -> "ILU0"]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xCG = solCG["Solution"];
```

> 141.175
>
> 32.0759
>
> 1.70319

I'd like to point out that a major part of the time needed by UMFPACK is due to the OS's memory management (I have only 16 GB of RAM installed.)

With slightly fine tuned parameters, the geometric multigrid solver performs even better:

```
S = GMGLinearSolve[A, J]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
solGMG = S[b, "Tolerance" -> 1. 10^-4,
     "StartingVectorSmoothingCounts" -> 6,
     "PreSmoothingCounts" -> 4,
     "PostSmoothingCounts" -> 4
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
xGMG = solGMG["Solution"];
```

> 0.405304
>
> 0.242293

You can inspect `Dataset@solGMG` and see for yourself that only two(!) V-cycles were needed. So, `S` can solve the same equation with hundreds(!) of right hand sides before Pardiso has finished factorization and before it can start the first actual solve. So in practice, even the `LinearSolveFunction` objects generated by `LinearSolve` will hardly make up for this difference.

### Errors

```
Max[Abs[xUMFPACK - xPardiso]]
Max[Abs[xUMFPACK - xCG]]
Max[Abs[xUMFPACK - xGMG]]
```

> 1.42109*10^-14
>
> 6.63873*10^-6
>
> 3.34638*10^-6

At first glance, this does not look that good for the iterative solvers, *but* when taking also the discretization error into account, these errors are negligible:

```
xTrue = Map[v, RList[[1]]["Coordinates"]];
Max[Abs[xTrue - xPardiso]]/Max[Abs[xTrue]]
Max[Abs[xTrue - xCG]]/Max[Abs[xTrue]]
Max[Abs[xTrue - xGMG]]/Max[Abs[xTrue]]
```

> 0.00298862
>
> 0.00299525
>
> 0.00298605

Comment: is it possible that we can use MG Solver as the standard procedures in MMA in future?

Comment: That's something you have to ask the people from Wolfram Research. In general, MG solvers use a lot of specific information about a linear system (here I use the knowledge that the matrix stems from the discretization of an elliptic operator and that there is a hierarchy of meshes). So, the effort for providing such a tool would be a bit limited, e.g. to linear systems from FEM---and even within that area, not all meshes are equally suitable.

Comment: That's why it is very unlikely that such a solver will be included in a future MMA distribution. And that's also why I stopped working on this project. At least for now.

Comment: I tried your code. It is really amazing. Much faster than the Pardiso option.

Comment: @hrlen Thank you! =)