# Catmull-Clark and Doo-Sabin Subdivision Implementations

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, mesh, code-request, smoothing

I want to work on subdivision surfaces. Unfortunately, I don’t have any source code to start with. I need some Mathematica codes for applying Catmull-Clark and Doo-Sabin methods. I would like to request anyone on this platform who have such codes to kindly share them with me.

The codes I have from: http://hakenberg.de/subdivision/enclosed_volume.htm are giving the error code:

> Part::partd: Part specification DooSabinListAlt[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: There is an implementation of Catmull-Clark on [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface#Mathematica)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Catmull-Clark Subdivision

Indeed, I have some code for Catmull-Clark subdivision and I planned to post it here for quite some time. This seems to be a good opportunity.

The code is optimized for performance, so it involves a lot of `CompiledFunction` and `SparseArray` hacks. I am sorry if you find it somewhat unidiomatic.

`CatmullClarkSubdivisionMatrix` creates the, well, subdivision matrix while the actual subdivision is performed by `CatmullClarkSubdivide`. The code below assumes that the surface is a manifold-like polyhedral mesh in $\mathbb{R}^3$, possibly with boundary and not necessarily orientable.

Before we start, you might be also interested in Loop subdivision; that one is implemented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161332).

### Application

First, we have the load the code from the section "Implementation" below. Then we can employ the function `CatmullClarkSubdivide`:

```
pts = N[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}];
polys = {{4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {8, 7, 3, 4}, {5, 8, 4, 1}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};

M = polymesh[pts, polys];

MList = NestList[CatmullClarkSubdivide, M, 4];

GraphicsRow[
 GridMeshPlot /@ MList,
 ImageSize -> Full
 ]
```

[image]

A somewhat more complex example:

```
R = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "MeshRegion"];
M = polymesh[MeshCoordinates[R], MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]];
MList = NestList[CatmullClarkSubdivide, M, 3];
GraphicsRow[
 MeshPlot /@ MList, 
 ImageSize -> Full
 ]
```

[image]

Two ways to subdivide the boundary:

```
pts = N[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}];
polys = {{4, 3, 2, 1},(*{1,2,6,5},*){2, 3, 7, 6}, {8, 7, 3, 4}, {5, 8, 4, 1}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
M = polymesh[pts, polys];
```

With averaging, applying the standard $(1/8, 1/2, 1/8)$-subdivision along the boundary curves:

```
MList = NestList[
   CatmullClarkSubdivide[#, "AverageBoundaryPoints" -> True] &, 
   M, 4];
GraphicsRow[GridMeshPlot /@ MList, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

And without averaging:

[image]

### Implementation

```
getEdgesFromPolygons = Compile[{{f, _Integer, 1}},
   Table[
    {
     Min[Compile`GetElement[f, i], Compile`GetElement[f, Mod[i + 1, Length[f], 1]]], 
     Max[Compile`GetElement[f, i], Compile`GetElement[f, Mod[i + 1, Length[f], 1]]]
     },
    {i, 1, Length[f]}
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

getSubdividedPolygons = 
  Compile[{{qq, _Integer, 1}, {ee, _Integer, 1}, {n, _Integer}},
   Table[
    {
     Compile`GetElement[qq, i],
     Compile`GetElement[ee, i],
     n,
     Compile`GetElement[ee, Mod[i - 1, Length[qq], 1]]
     },
    {i, 1, Length[qq]}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

AccumulateIntegerList = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
   Block[{c = 0, r = 0},
    Table[
     If[i <= Length[list],
      r = c; c += Compile`GetElement[list, i]; r,
      c
      ]
     , {i, 1, Length[list] + 1}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

cExtractIntegerFromSparseMatrix = Compile[
   {{vals, _Integer, 1}, {rp, _Integer, 1}, {ci, _Integer, 
     1}, {background, _Integer},
    {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
   Block[{k, c},
    k = Compile`GetElement[rp, i] + 1;
    c = Compile`GetElement[rp, i + 1];
    While[k < c + 1 && Compile`GetElement[ci, k] != j, ++k];
    If[k == c + 1, background, Compile`GetElement[vals, k]]
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

ToPack = Developer`ToPackedArray;

polymesh::usage = "";
polymesh /: polymesh[points0_, polygons0_] :=
 Module[{polygons},
  polygons = ToPack[polygons0];
  polymesh[
   Association[
    "MeshCoordinates" -> ToPack[N[points0]],
    "MeshCells" -> Association[
      0 -> Partition[Range[Length[points0]], 1],
      1 -> DeleteDuplicates[ToPack[Flatten[getEdgesFromPolygons[polygons], 1]]],
      2 -> polygons
      ]
    ]
   ]
  ];

polymesh /: MeshCoordinates[M_polymesh] := M[[1]][["MeshCoordinates"]];

polymesh /: MeshCells[M_polymesh, d_Integer] := M[[1]][["MeshCells", Key[d]]];

polymesh /: MeshCellCount[M_polymesh, d_Integer] := Length[MeshCells[M, d]];

GridMeshPlot::usage = "";
polymesh /: GridMeshPlot[M_polymesh] := Graphics3D[{
   ColorData[97][1], Specularity[White, 30], EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}];
   GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[M], Polygon[MeshCells[M, 2]]],
   },
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  Boxed -> False
  ];

MeshPlot::usage = "";
polymesh /: MeshPlot[M_polymesh] := Graphics3D[{
   ColorData[97][1], Specularity[White, 30], EdgeForm[],
   GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[M], Polygon[MeshCells[M, 2]]],
   },
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  Boxed -> False
  ];

SignedPolygonsNeighEdges::usage = "";
polymesh /: SignedPolygonsNeighEdges[M_polymesh] := 
 Module[{edges, n, A00, i, j},
  edges = MeshCells[M, 1];
  n = MeshCellCount[M, 0];
  A00 = SparseArray`SparseArraySort@SparseArray[
     Rule[
      Join[edges, Transpose[Transpose[edges][[{2, 1}]]]],
      Join[Range[1, Length[edges]], Range[-1, -Length[edges], -1]]
      ],
     {n, n}
     ];
  {i, j} = Transpose[Join @@ With[{cf = Compile[{{p, _Integer, 1}},
         Transpose[{p, RotateLeft[p]}],
         RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
         Parallelization -> True
         ]},
      cf[MeshCells[M, 2]]
      ]];
  Internal`PartitionRagged[
   cExtractIntegerFromSparseMatrix[
    A00["NonzeroValues"], A00["RowPointers"], 
    Flatten[A00["ColumnIndices"]], 0, i, j
    ],
   Length /@ MeshCells[M, 2]
   ]
  ];

SubdividedPolygons::usage = "";
polymesh /: SubdividedPolygons[M_polymesh] :=
  With[{
    n0 = MeshCellCount[M, 0],
    n1 = MeshCellCount[M, 1],
    n2 = MeshCellCount[M, 2]
    },
   Flatten[getSubdividedPolygons[
     MeshCells[M, 2],
     Abs[SignedPolygonsNeighEdges[M]] + n0,
     Range[1 + n0 + n1, n0 + n1 + n2]
     ], 1]
   ];

getConnectivityMatrix::usage = "";
getConnectivityMatrix[n_Integer, cells_List] :=
  With[{m = Length[cells]},
   If[m > 0,
    Module[{A, lens, nn, rp},
     lens = Compile[{{cell, _Integer, 1}},
        Length[cell],
        CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
        RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
        Parallelization -> True
        ][cells];
     rp = AccumulateIntegerList[lens];
     nn = rp[[-1]];
     A = SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {m, n}, 0, {1, {rp, Partition[Flatten[cells], 1]}, ConstantArray[1, nn]}}]
    ,
    {}
    ]
   ];

getMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix::usage = "";
getMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[A_?MatrixQ, d_Integer] :=  
  If[Length[A] > 0,
   With[{B = A.A\[Transpose]},
    SparseArray[UnitStep[B - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[B]] - d]]
    ],
   {}
   ];

getMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[Ad10_?MatrixQ, A0d2_?MatrixQ, d1_Integer, 
   d2_Integer] := If[(Length[Ad10] > 0) && (Length[A0d2] > 0),
   With[{B = Ad10.A0d2}, SparseArray[
     If[d1 == d2,
      UnitStep[B - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[B]] - d1],
      UnitStep[B - (Min[d1, d2] + 1)]]
     ]
    ],
   {}
   ];

MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix::usage = "";

polymesh /: MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M_polymesh, 0, 0 _] := SparseArray[
  Join[MeshCells[M, 1], 
    Transpose[Reverse[Transpose[MeshCells[M, 1]]]]] -> 1,
  {1, 1} MeshCellCount[M, 0]
  ];

polymesh /: MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M_polymesh, 0 _, d_Integer] := 
  With[{cells = MeshCells[M, d]},
   If[Length[cells] > 0,
    Transpose[getConnectivityMatrix[MeshCellCount[M, 0], MeshCells[M, d]]],
    {}
    ]
   ];

polymesh /: MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M_polymesh, d_Integer, 0 _] :=
  With[{A = MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 0, d]},
   If[Length[A] > 0,
    Transpose[MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 0, d]],
    {}
    ]
   ];

polymesh /: MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M_polymesh, d_Integer, d_Integer] := 
 getMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, d, 0], d]

polymesh /: MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M_polymesh, d_Integer] := 
  MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, d, d];

polymesh /: MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M_polymesh, d1_Integer, d2_Integer] := 
  Module[{r, m1, m2},
   {m1, m2} = MinMax[{d1, d2}];
   r = getMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[
     MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, m1, 0],
     MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 0, m2],
     m1,
     m2
     ];
   If[d1 < d2, r, If[Length[r] > 0, Transpose[r], {}]]
   ];

CatmullClarkSubdivisionMatrix::usage = "";
polymesh /: CatmullClarkSubdivisionMatrix[M_polymesh, OptionsPattern[{"AverageBoundaryPoints" -> True}]] := 
  Module[{avgbndpQ, A02, A01, A10, valences, bplist, edgevalencelist, χbndp, χbndpcomp, χbnde, χbndecomp, belist, A20, A12, vB, eB, pB, n0, n1},      
   avgbndpQ = OptionValue["AverageBoundaryPoints"];       
   n0 = MeshCellCount[M, 0];
   n1 = MeshCellCount[M, 1];
   A02 = MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 0, 2];
   A20 = Transpose[A02];
   A01 = MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 0, 1];
   A10 = Transpose[A01];
   A12 = getMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[A10, A02, 1, 2];
   valences = N[Total[A01, {2}]];
   belist = Random`Private`PositionsOf[Total[A12, {2}], 1];
   
   χbnde = SparseArray[Transpose[{belist}] -> 1, {n1}, 0];
   χbndecomp = (1. - Normal[χbnde]);
   bplist = Union @@ MeshCells[M, 1][[belist]];
   χbndp = SparseArray[Partition[bplist, 1] -> 1, {n0}, 0];
   χbndpcomp = (1. - Normal[χbndp]);
   
   pB = A20 SparseArray[1./(Length /@ MeshCells[M, 2])];
   eB = (0.5 χbnde) Transpose[χbndp A01] + SparseArray[0.25 χbndecomp] (A10 + A12.pB);
   vB = Plus[
      SparseArray[χbndpcomp/valences^2] (A02.pB + A01.A10), 
      DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[χbndpcomp (1. - 3./valences) + If[avgbndpQ, 0.75, 1.] Normal[χbndp]]]
      ];
   If[avgbndpQ,
     vB += (0.125 χbndp) Transpose[χbndp MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 0, 0]]
     ];
   Join[vB, eB, pB]
   ];

CatmullClarkSubdivide::usage = ""; 
polymesh /: CatmullClarkSubdivide[M0_polymesh, OptionsPattern[{
    "Subdivisions" -> 1,
    "AverageBoundaryPoints" -> True
    }]
  ] :=
 Module[{t, M, A},
  M = M0;
  If[OptionValue["Subdivisions"] > 0,
   PrintTemporary["Subdividing..."];
   t = AbsoluteTiming[
      A = CatmullClarkSubdivisionMatrix[M, "AverageBoundaryPoints" -> OptionValue["AverageBoundaryPoints"]];
      M = polymesh[A.MeshCoordinates[M], SubdividedPolygons[M]];
      ][[1]];
   PrintTemporary["Subdivision done. Time elapsed: ", ToString[t]];
   ];
  If[OptionValue["Subdivisions"] > 1,
   M = CatmullClarkSubdivide[M,
     "Subdivisions" -> OptionValue["Subdivisions"] - 1,
     "AverageBoundaryPoints" -> OptionValue["AverageBoundaryPoints"]
     ]
   ];
  M
  ];
```

Comment: (+1) thanks for posting. One thing I do not get is the purpose of such sub divisions. What are they used for?

Comment: Dear Henrik Schumacher, I appreciate your help since this is exactly what i was looking for Catmull-Clark . Anyone else with Doo-Sabin subdivision surface codes can also share them with us.

Comment: @user21 Finite elements! ;) The limiting surfaces are proven to be C^2 apart from "exceptional" points where the initial mesh does not have the generic valence (for triangle meshes, the generic valence is 6 and for quad meshes, the generic valuence is 4). So, you get $C^1$-finite elements for surfaces. _But_ the curvature aorund the exceptional vertices blows up so much that subdivision surface are actually not overly useful for minimizing curvature energies... (you have to add many quadrature points around the curvature singularieties.

Comment: @user21 The fine thing about the limiting surfaces: You can evaluate also _exact_ positions and normals with finite cost from the initial mesh (the so-called "control mesh").

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, fair enough but the shape of your original Cubiod changed to the Ball? Do you then project the solution pack or something? I must miss something obvious.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, so the usefulness of something like this is a local patch?

Comment: @user21 So, subdivision surfaces are not that much used for finite element analysis, although there has been a small hype in the graphics processing community a few years ago. Mostly, subdivision surfaces are used as a flexible tool for surface design quite similar how splines and NURBS surfaces are used: The vertices of the initial mesh provide you with controls to deform the limiting surface in a surprisingly intuitive and predictable way. And you have also a hierarchy of mesh resolutions, so you can generate quick previews and high quality meshes with the same pipeline.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, OK, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @user21 Btw.: Catmull-Clark subdivision became famous also because Pixar uses them for modelling their animated movies...

Comment: @user21 You're welcome.

Comment: @RongJin You're also welcome and thanks for the accepting the answer.

Comment: @RongJin I play also with the idea to implement Doo-Sabin. So far, I ruled it out because the limiting surfaces are only $C^0$ everywhere and $C^1$ genericallywhile Loop- and Catmull-Clark subivision surfaces are $C^1$ everywhere and $C^2$ generically. I am not sure whether it is worth the effort.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, You can still share the codes (Doo-Sabin) if you have them . I will deal with the continuity after manipulating them.

Comment: @RongJin I haven't implemented Doo-Sabin, yet, and I actually don't have the time at the moment... But you can try on your own: The data structure `polymens` and the `MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix` will be certainly useful.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Okay. I will try my best.

Comment: I just have to ask, because I might learn something from it, why do you prefer `TagSetDelayed` instead of just a normal `SetDelayed`? (Brilliant implementation btw)

Comment: @C.E. Because `polymesh` is supposed to be an object; inheritance is quite easily implemented with tags. And because I'd like to overload  `MeshRegion` functions like `MeshCoordinates` and `MeshCells` etc. and this way, (i) I don't have to unprotect the symbols an (ii) I don't have to be afraid of future name collisions (in particular, I may use pure PascalCase instead of camelCase, which I find convenient... Germans like me have kind a fetish in capitalization of words, you know... ;) ).

Comment: @C.E. Moreover, in my own packages, I have plenty of similar mesh related data types (e.g., for pure triangle and quad mesh, tet meshes, hex meshes,...) so that there are _many_ overloaded  functions. Using `TagSetDelayed` helps _Mathematica_ with looking up the appropriate definitions  since it can restrict its search to the specific tag. And because you can do `??polymesh`...

Comment: @C.E. Btw.: Thank you for the compliment!

Comment: ok, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @C.E. You're always welcome! =)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92686/discussion-on-answer-by-henrik-schumacher-catmull-clark-and-doo-sabin-subdivisio).

Answer (score 19):

## Doo-Sabin Subdivision

To my own surprise, Doo-Sabin subdivision is in many ways much easier to implement than Catmull-Clark subdivision. The only real problem I met was to compute the faces created at vertices correctly. The method I use for this is reasonably fast for meshes with not-to-high vertex degrees, but it is not guaranteed that the subdivision of an oriented mesh is again oriented.

### Application

```
a = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3, 3}];
Do[a[[i, j, k]] = 0;, {i, {1, 3}}, {j, {1, 3}}, {k, {1, 3}}];
R = RegionBoundary[ArrayMesh[a]];
M = polymesh[MeshCoordinates[R], MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]];

MList = NestList[DooSabinSubdivide, M, 4];
GraphicsRow[GridMeshPlot /@ MList, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

An example with nontrivial boundary:

```
pts = N[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}];
polys = {{4, 3, 2, 1},(*{1,2,6,5},*){2, 3, 7, 6}, {8, 7, 3, 4}, {5, 8, 4, 1}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
M = polymesh[pts, polys];

MList = NestList[DooSabinSubdivide, M, 4];
GraphicsRow[GridMeshPlot /@ MList, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

### Implementation

*In addition* to the code [from my other post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195494), one requires the following. This version also features correct(?) handling of boundaries.

```
getDooSabinSubdivisionMasks = Compile[{{n, _Real}},
   Block[{ω, a},
    ω = 2. Pi/n;
    a = (n + 5.)/(4. n);
    Flatten@Table[If[i == j, a, (3. + 2. Cos[ω (i - j)])/(4. n)], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

getDooSabinCombinatorics = Compile[{{face, _Integer, 1}, {idx, _Integer}},
   Flatten[
    Table[
     {i, Compile`GetElement[face, j]},
     {i, idx - Length[face] + 1, idx}, {j, 1, Length[face]}],
    1
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

DooSabinSubdivisionMatrix::usage = "";
polymesh /: DooSabinSubdivisionMatrix[M_polymesh] := 
  Module[{lens, acc, n0, n2, polys, L, A, A12, bndelist, edgesneighpolys, e1, e2, i, j, newbndplist, bndn1}, 
   n0 = MeshCellCount[M, 0];
   n2 = MeshCellCount[M, 2];
   polys = MeshCells[M, 2];
   lens = ToPack[Length /@ polys];
   acc = AccumulateIntegerList[lens];
   L = SparseArray[
     Rule[
      Join @@ getDooSabinCombinatorics[MeshCells[M, 2], Rest[acc]], 
      Join @@ getDooSabinSubdivisionMasks[Range[Max[lens]]][[lens]]], {acc[[-1]], n0}];
   
   A12 = MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 1, 2];
   bndelist = Random`Private`PositionsOf[Total[A12, {2}], 1];
   If[Length[bndelist] > 0,
    A = SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {n2, n0}, 0, {1, {acc, Partition[Join @@ polys, 1]}, Join @@ (Most[acc] + Range[lens])}};
    edgesneighpolys = A12[[bndelist]]["AdjacencyLists"];
    {e1, e2} = Transpose[MeshCells[M, 1][[bndelist]]];
    {i, j} = Transpose[Riffle[Transpose[{Flatten[edgesneighpolys], e1}], Transpose[{Flatten[edgesneighpolys], e2}]]];
    newbndplist = cExtractIntegerFromSparseMatrix[A["NonzeroValues"], A["RowPointers"], Flatten[A["ColumnIndices"]], 0, i, j];
    bndn1 = Length[bndelist];
    L[[newbndplist]] = 
     SparseArray[
      Rule[
        Transpose[{Join[Range[2 bndn1], Range[2 bndn1]], Join[Riffle[e1, e2], Riffle[e2, e1]]}], Join[ConstantArray[3./4., 2 bndn1], 
        ConstantArray[1./4., 2 bndn1]]], {2 bndn1, n0}];
    ];
   L
   ];

getDooSabinEdgeQuads = Compile[{{edge, _Integer, 1}, {polyidx, _Integer, 1}},
   {
    {Compile`GetElement[polyidx, 1], Compile`GetElement[edge, 1]},
    {Compile`GetElement[polyidx, 1], Compile`GetElement[edge, 2]},
    {Compile`GetElement[polyidx, 2], Compile`GetElement[edge, 2]},
    {Compile`GetElement[polyidx, 2], Compile`GetElement[edge, 1]}
    },
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

getDooSabinVertexFaces = Compile[{{dualedges, _Integer, 2}, {idx, _Integer, 1}},
   Block[{n, q, p, i, k, c, j},
    n = Length[idx];
    q = dualedges[[idx]];
    p = Table[0, n];
    p[[1]] = Compile`GetElement[q, 1, 1];
    p[[2]] = c = Compile`GetElement[q, 1, 2];
    i = 1;
    k = 2;
    While[k < n,
     j = 1;
     While[
      And[j < n, Or[i == j, c != Compile`GetElement[q, j, 1] && c != Compile`GetElement[q, j, 2]]],
      j++
      ];
     k++;
     i = j;
     p[[k]] = c = If[c == Compile`GetElement[q, j, 1],
        Compile`GetElement[q, j, 2],
        Compile`GetElement[q, j, 1]
        ];
     ];
    p
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

DooSabinSubdividedPolygons::usage = "";
polymesh /: DooSabinSubdividedPolygons[M_polymesh] := 
  Module[{lens, acc, polys, edges, edgesneighpolys, n2, n0, A, B, A12, edgevalences, vertexfaces, edgefaces, facefaces, i, j, t, intelist, bndelist, intplist, intedges},
   n0 = MeshCellCount[M, 0];
   polys = MeshCells[M, 2];
   n2 = Length[polys];
   lens = ToPack[Length /@ polys];
   acc = AccumulateIntegerList[lens];
   
   facefaces = Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[acc[[-1]]], lens];
   
   A12 = MeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 1, 2];
   edgevalences = Total[A12, {2}];
   intelist = Random`Private`PositionsOf[edgevalences, 2];
   bndelist = Random`Private`PositionsOf[edgevalences, 1];
   intedges = MeshCells[M, 1][[intelist]];
   intplist = Complement[Range[n0], Flatten[MeshCells[M, 1][[bndelist]]]];
   edgesneighpolys = A12[[intelist]]["AdjacencyLists"];
   {i, j} = 
    Transpose[Join @@ getDooSabinEdgeQuads[intedges, edgesneighpolys]];
   A = SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {n2, n0}, 0, {1, {acc, Partition[Join @@ polys, 1]}, Join @@ (Most[acc] + Range[lens])}};
   edgefaces = Partition[
     cExtractIntegerFromSparseMatrix[
      A["NonzeroValues"],
      A["RowPointers"],
      Flatten[A["ColumnIndices"]], 0, i, j
      ],
     4
     ];
   
   B = SparseArray[
     Transpose[{Flatten[intedges], Range[2 Length[intelist]]}] -> 1,
     {n0, 2 Length[intelist]}
     ];
   vertexfaces = getDooSabinVertexFaces[
     ArrayReshape[edgefaces[[All, {1, 4, 2, 3}]], {2 Length[edgefaces], 2}],
     B[[intplist]]["AdjacencyLists"]
     ];
   Join[facefaces, edgefaces, vertexfaces]
   ];

DooSabinSubdivide::usage = "";
polymesh /: DooSabinSubdivide[M0_polymesh, OptionsPattern[{"Subdivisions" -> 1}]
   ] := Module[{lens, acc, pat, polys, edges, edgesneighpolys, m, n, nn, A, B, A02, valences, vertexfaces, edgefaces, facefaces, i, j, t, M},
   PrintTemporary["Subdividing..."];
   t = AbsoluteTiming[
      If[OptionValue["Subdivisions"] > 0,
       M = M0;
       M = polymesh[
         DooSabinSubdivisionMatrix[M].MeshCoordinates[M],
         DooSabinSubdividedPolygons[M]
         ];
       ,
       M = M0;
       ]
      ][[1]];
   PrintTemporary["Doo-Sabin subdivision done. Time elapsed: ", ToString[t]];
   
   If[OptionValue["Subdivisions"] > 1,
    M = DooSabinSubdivide[M, "Subdivisions" -> OptionValue["Subdivisions"] - 1]
    ];
   M
   ];
```